# Why the following error is showing while importing an project?

Tags: android, android-studio

Why the following error is showing in android studio while importing a external project (https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok/tree/Starter-code)?

Error: Gradle 'ud839_Miwok-Starter-code' project refresh failed

Error:Content is not allowed in prolog.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean and to rebuild your project. This is located at the Build Menu.

If this does not help, please show more details like your project tree, especially your resource diretory. It may also be that you created something at a place where it is not allowed to be.